# google cloud functions API cannot be enabled , error is prerequisites failed to complete

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have a project set up on GCP woth biling enabled. I am not able to enable google cloud function API. I cannot get past this step. Please help.I get the error :
[Error detalils](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90pR0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be seeing [this issue that is reported on the Firebase status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/17022).

> We are experiencing an issue with Cloud Functions where some projects which have not used Functions before may be unable to start using it. We are investigating the issue and will provide more information soon.

If so, check that status page for updates.